# Numbers "disappearing" off right of field box in IE

Tags: html

Works fine in chrome but not in IE. I am using ASP.NET MVC5 with bootstrap

[image]

Comment: Just hit F12 in IE (or right click and "inspect element") and play with the paddings and margins...

Answer (score 0):

Andrei was right.

setting

```
.form-control{
    padding-right:2px;
}
```

solved the problem